# Cannot Assign Key => Value to Foreach Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I have the following array of countries `($countryIso = array("US","BR","CL");)`  and my idea is to create a new array to display the following schema:

> ('US', 200)

I tried to create the following structure:

```
    $countryIso = array("US","BR","CL");

    foreach ($countryIso as $isocode) {
        $productcalc[] = "'" . strtoupper($isocode) . "'" . ',' . number_format($this->product->calculate($product = $product, $countryIso = $isocode), 0, '.', ',');
    }
```

Despite I can create a look alike format, I realized that the array is not well formed. When I checked the output displays the following:

> Array ( [0] => 'US',200

being the key is [0] and not US.

Any idea of how can I create a key => value result with

> Array ( [US] => 200

using the foreach structure in my code? I tried with variants like array_combine to combine countryIso array with productcalc array but with no success

Comment: `$array['US'] = 200;`

Comment: `$array[$isocode] = 200;`

Comment: array([$isocode],[$productcalc]) displays     [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 'US',900
                    [1] => 'BR',1,215
                    [2] => 'CL',1,446
                )

        )but array still [0]

Comment: if you are adding information to your question. **please edit it into your question**

Comment: Not sure what this piece of code is supposed to be doing `calculate($product = $product, $countryIso = $isocode)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your iso array and simply just [combine](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) the arrays:

```
<?php
    $iso = ['US', 'BR', 'CL'];
    $values = [200, 300, 400]; # obviously populate this with your actual values

    $newArray = array_combine($iso, $values); # array_combine($keys, $values)
    echo '<pre>'. print_r($newArray, 1) .'</pre>';
```

**Edit: Further thoughts if Values are got via iso value**

```
<?php
    $iso = ['US', 'BR', 'CL'];
    $newArray = [];

    foreach ($iso as $val)
    {
        $newArray[$val] = getValueFromIso($val); # not a real function - just an example
    }
```

Comment: the first one works perfect, but in my case the foreach takes countryIso as value for calculation and I cannot asign key =>value like $countryIso as key =>value

Comment: @s_h not sure I follow the second part of your comment sorry haha but if the first one works and you can create two arrays like that then I'm happy to help :)

Comment: thank you, I was missing the following concept $newArray[$val]. happy new year !.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the array with the correct values.

```
$countryIso =[
    "US" => 200,
    "BR" => 300,
    "CL" => 400,
];
```

If the values need to be calculated use:

```
$countryIso = array("US","BR","CL");

foreach ($countryIso as $isocode) {
    $productcalc[strtoupper($isocode)] = number_format($this->product->calculate($product = $product, $countryIso = $isocode), 0, '.', ',');
}
```

Now $productcalc is the array you need.

Comment: I understand, but my problem is that I cannot assign the key based on $productcalc result. like $countryIso US and productcalc = 200.